# Can i query 2 distinct collections in Solr query?

Tags: solr, solrcloud, sunspot-solr

I have a requirement where i need to display data of two different solr collection on a page. But the two collections don't have any common field or relation.

e.g.

```
`Collection 1 fields -> field1(unique key), feild 2, field 3`

Collection 2 fields -> field4(unique key), feild 5
```

Results should be combination of collection 1 data based on field1 and collection 2 data based on field4.

Comment: yes you can query using the streaming expression

Comment: Even though the suggestion is that the schemas should be identical to do any useful querying, you might be able to create a alias that is backed by two collections: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/aliases.html - however, you might need to at least have a `id` field in both. If necessary, add the same fields to both indexes (just so that they're defined) but just use the files you need.

Answer (score 0):

> innerJoin Wraps two streams, Left and Right. For every tuple in Left
> which exists in Right a tuple containing the fields of both tuples
> will be emitted. This supports one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one,
> and many-to-many inner join scenarios. The tuples are emitted in the
> order in which they appear in the Left stream. Both streams must be
> sorted by the fields being used to determine equality (the 'on'
> parameter). If both tuples contain a field of the same name then the
> value from the Right stream will be used in the emitted tuple. You can
> wrap the incoming streams with a select(…​) expression to be specific
> about which field values are included in the emitted tuple

You can make use of Solr Streaming expression.

```
innerJoin(
  search(Collection1, q="*:*", qt="/export", fl="field1, fields2", sort="commonField asc"),
  search(Collection2, q="*:*", qt="/export", fl="field3, fields4", sort="commonField  asc"),
  on="commonField "
)
```

Please refer the solr link for more option on the same
[Solr Streaming](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/stream-decorator-reference.html)

Comment: Issue is, both the collections don't have any common field.

Comment: Is there any other field with different name but having common value

Comment: No(no common value), just image data is coming from 2 independent sources and they need to be displayed on a single page.

Comment: then its not possible ...does it possible in RDBMS...? it does not make any sense...